# Calculating Average Monthly Consumption

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on an self improvement inventory management project in Laravel 4 but can't figure out the best way to perform the average monthly consumption (AMC) calculation.

I have two tables i.e **commodities** table (`id,item_name,price`) and **stockcard** (`id, item_id, qty_in, qty_out,transaction_date`) from which i should derive the AMC calculation.

```
FORMULA = (sum of current month's qty_out + sum of previous two month's qty_out) / 3
```

Can anyone bail me out on how to go about it in plain PHP and mysql?

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using conditional aggregation for example

```
   drop table if exists t;

create table t(item int,qty_out int , dt date);

insert into t values
(1,1,'2018-09-01'),(1,1,'2018-10-01'),(1,1,'2018-11-01');

select item,
         sum(case when year(dt)*12 + month(dt) = year(now()) * 12 + month(now()) then qty_out else 0 end) thismm,
         sum(case when year(dt)*12 + month(dt) = (year(now()) * 12 + month(now()) -1) or
                            year(dt)*12 + month(dt) = (year(now()) * 12 + month(now()) -2) then qty_out else 0 end) last2mm,
         (sum(case when year(dt)*12 + month(dt) = year(now()) * 12 + month(now()) then qty_out else 0 end) +
         sum(case when year(dt)*12 + month(dt) = (year(now()) * 12 + month(now()) -1) or
                            year(dt)*12 + month(dt) = (year(now()) * 12 + month(now()) -2) then qty_out else 0 end)
         ) / 3  amc
from t
where year(dt)*12 + month(dt) >= (year(now()) * 12 + month(now()) -2)
group by item ;
+------+-----------+-------+--------+
| item | thismonth | last2 | amc    |
+------+-----------+-------+--------+
|    1 |         1 |     2 | 1.0000 |
+------+-----------+-------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Note the conversion to month number to simplify where dates go over a year end.
Of course if you are looking for a 3 month rolling average then that would be a different question.

Comment: You are a life saver. This is exactly what i was looking for and works perfectly

Comment: @O'Byron If an answer has helped you. You should consider marking it as accepted answer (click on checkmark besides the answer to turn it green). Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)